# Use jq to filter json with regex, and the rest objects split into two separate chunks, containing half of the remaining objects each

Tags: json, awk, jq

Given the following json:

```
[{
        "_id": {
            "productno": "5d538a"
        },
        "serial": "15947",
        "description": "text"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "productno": "5d587"
        },
        "serial": "15948",
        "description": "text"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "productno": "5d5c38c"
        },
        "serial": "15949",
        "description": "more text"
    },{
        "_id": {
            "productno": "5d5c38c"
        },
        "serial": "15967",
        "description": "more text"
    }
]
```

i need to filter based on a list of numbers, say for our example

```
15947
15948
```

(i have a list of thousands of serials numbers, that are separated by the newline)
I have tried with

```
map(select(test("\\^15947$|^15948$\\b")))
```

expected output:
file A:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "productno": "5d538a"
  },
  "serial": "15947",
  "description": "text"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "productno": "5d587"
  },
  "serial": "15948",
  "description": "text"
}
```

and file B: (since there are two more objects, each file will have one object)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "productno": "5d5c38c"
  },
  "serial": "15949",
  "description": "more text"
}
```

and finally file C:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "productno": "5d5c38c"
  },
  "serial": "15967",
  "description": "more text"
}
```

Comment: jq and awk would be just fine for me

Comment: @ogusismail - Yes, -c is the key.  Inconvenient, but reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a large number of serial numbers to check, using a large regex is inadvisable.

If you just had to produce a stream of the objects satisfying the serial number criterion, you could use the invocation:

```
jq --rawfile sn serial-numbers.txt -f select.jq input.json
```

where select.jq contains

```
INDEX($sn | splits("\n") | select(length>0); .) as $dict
| .[]
| select($dict[.serial])
```

The key to using jq to partition the objects into three files is to tag the objects and invoke jq with the -c command-line option.  You then process the tagged output using a tool such as `awk`.  This last part has been covered in several other SO Q&As, so I'll just focus on the tagging part, which can be accomplished using `foreach`:

```
INDEX($sn | splits("\n") | select(length>0); .) as $dict
| foreach .[] as $in ({parity:0};
    if ($in | $dict[.serial])
    then .code = 2
    else .code = .parity
    | .parity |= (.+1 % 2)
    end;
    .code, $in )
```

### awk-based solution

For example:

```
awk 'NR%2==1 {fn=$1 ".json"; next} {print >> fn}'
```

Comment: i would appreciate also an example on how to use awk in the answer, since i am totally unfamiliar with it,thank you